# Ошибка соединения: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

[image]
Пытаюсь подключить к драйверу PostgreSQL, выходит ошибка, что драйвер не найден. Все, что делал - скачивал драйвер на официальном сайте(https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads) для Windows x86-64, ничего не изменилось

Comment: База данных устанавливалась?